# Same file to two location in WIX 3.5

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I am trying to add the same file to two diferent locations. I am deploying an SDK and want certain files to reside in .\Binaries* as well as .\Samples\SampleX* and also .\Editor*

The Answer is probably going to be to put them in the GAC,but we realy want them on disk so they are disributable.

Comment: Why not add it twice as two separate components to your installer? A component will always be installed only once.

Comment: You can't do that as it detects that you are adding the same source twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [CopyFile Element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_copyfile.htm)